# Syntax error on UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I am trying to take the data from excel sheet cells and update the mysql table using this query

> `sqlstr = "UPDATE " & table4 & " SET price = CASE WHEN key_id = '" & Cells(i, 1) & "' " & " THEN " & Cells(i, 8) & " " & " WHEN key_id = '" & Cells(i, 2) & "' " & " THEN " & Cells(i, 9) & " " & " ELSE: price "`

It gives me an error:

> Syntax to use near ':price'

Well, if i remove at the end the word price it gives me an error:

> Syntax to use near "

I guess I am missing some quotes somewhere. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please show the results of `sqlstr` after it has been created.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The query doesn't even go through

Comment: Print the value of `sqlstr` so we can see what it looks like after variable substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1**:

`" ELSE: price` shoule be `" ELSE " & price`

**Error 2**:

You are missing and `END` for the `CASE` clause

> `sqlstr = "UPDATE " & table4 & " SET price = CASE WHEN key_id = '" & Cells(i, 1) & "' THEN " & Cells(i, 8) & " WHEN key_id = '" & Cells(i, 2) & "' THEN " & Cells(i, 9) & " ELSE " & price & " END"`

Comment: It says Syntax near ':price END" at line 1

Comment: Oh holy crap!!!! IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANKK YOUUUU SO MUCH!!!!!! You the man!!!

Comment: How can I start to update the table from the excel sheet from row two and not the row one. Because row one contains the name fields

Comment: It appears you are using a loop with 'i' being the ROW. If you had 'For i = 1 to 999', then change it to 'For i = 2 to 999'   the solution is setting the value of 'i'

Comment: The rows loop should be 2nd to `Rows.count`

Comment: oh ok.  It works! Thank you so much once again @WayneG.Dunn and Ravinder